Units of Poynting vector (or flux of energy) and field intensity
In optics, the Poynting vector of an EM wave is
$$\boldsymbol{\mathcal S}=\frac{c}{4\pi}\,\mathbf E\wedge\mathbf H$$
and if I am not mistaken its units in the SI system should be $\mathrm{W/m^2}$, or in the cgs one, $\mathrm{erg/s/cm^2}$. I'm not sure either if this definition is valid for any unit system though.
Checking whether the equation above has the same units (using the SI system for convenience),
$$\mathrm{\frac{m}{s}\cdot\frac{V}{m}\cdot[\mathbf H]}\overset{!}{=}\mathrm{\frac{W}{m^2}}=\mathrm{\frac{J}{s\cdot m^2}}\iff [\mathbf H]=\mathrm{\frac{J}{V\cdot m^2}}=\mathrm{\frac{C}{m^2}}\ [?]$$
we find an erroneous unit for the field intensity.
What assumption is wrong in all of what I have stated? And what are the actual units of the field intensity in the SI and cgs systems?

That formula for $S$ is not valid in SI. Looks more like CGS. And there should not be any index $n$ there.

In SI units, the Poynting vector is ${\bf E}\times {\bf H}$.
The units are V m$^{-1}\times$  A m$^{-1}$ and since volts times amps is a power, then the units are W m$^{-2}$, power per unit area.
In cgs units, the Poynting vector is
$$ {\bf S} = \frac{c}{4\pi}\left({\bf E} \times \mu {\bf H}\right)\ , $$
where $\mu$ is the relative permeability (unitless) and both the E and H-field have the same units of (stat) V.cm$^{-1}$ and $c$ has units of cm.s$^{-1}$. The units of the Poynting vector are therefore (stat V)$^2$.cm$^{-1}$.s$^{-1}$ or, in base units g.cm.s$^{-2}$.cm$^{-1}$.s$^{-1}$ = g.s$^{-3}$.
Since the erg has units of g.cm$^2$.s$^{-2}$, then this reduces to erg/cm$^2$/s. Power per unit area.
